# If $G=\mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b$, find a particular subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $a$, $b$ be positive integers, and let $d$=gcd($a,b$) and $m$=lcm$[a,b]$. In the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b$, let $M$ be the subgroup generated by $(1,1)$. Find a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $G=M \oplus H$.

This comes from Problem 10 of section 7.5 of Abstract Algebra by Beachy and Blair.

I am trying to work through the problems, but I can not find how to begin this one. It comes after a section on the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Thank you very much for any help.

I am sorry for any grammar mistakes, it is not my native language.

Comment: Have you tried writing it up for $a=6$ and $b=10$? What have you gotten as $M$ and what would $H$ be then? Can you generalize it to other cases?